# MS Graph API - Is it possible for a bot to join an existing call not created by himself by using OnlineMeeting information?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I would like to know if it is possible for a bot to join / get an existing call ([Get Call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)) by using information provided by OnlineMeeting ([Get OnlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)) ?

I didn't find any information about link between onlinemeeting and call.

For example, A user create an online meeting by using graphapi ([Create onlinemeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)), is there a way for a bot to join call associated to this onlinemeeting if call has been initiated by user ?

When I tried to get call by using all ID found in OnlineMeeting, I got (depending which id I used between OnlineMeeting ID, OnlineMeeting Thread ID, OnlineMeeting Dialin ID) :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "8522",
    "message": "Call not found.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-04-01T23:09:35",
      "request-id": "XXXX",
      "client-request-id": "XXXX"
    }
  }
}
```

OR

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-04-01T23:12:00",
      "request-id": "XXXX",
      "client-request-id": "XXXX"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you call? Do you have permission?

Comment: hi @CarlZhao, I create onlinemeeting by graphapi, I forwarded joinurl to user, user connect to onlinemeeting (& initiate a call). I would like to be able to get this call id with bot. 
I have all required rights on graphapi (application type with all API scope needed) and on Teams/Skype side (CsApplicationAccessPolicy).

Comment: @Julien,Yes a user may initiate a peer-to-peer call with your bot or invite your bot into an existing multiparty call. Please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview).

Comment: @Julien,Please let us know does that help clarify.

Comment: thanks @Sridevi-MSFT it help to clarify but my goal was just to join an existing meeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question, I needed to use this process :
[Create call to Join scheduled meeting with service hosted media](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-5-join-scheduled-meeting-with-service-hosted-media)

What I didn't understood is we need to create a call object to join an existing online meeting (and not looking for getting an existing call).